# Failed to run maven javafx application and some error in pom file

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml, netbeans-11

I am trying to run a JavaFX application under Maven. When I run the program it shows some error.

> Error: Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on
>   project Calculator: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid
>   -> [Help 1]

At which part i should make the change in my pom.xml file.

```
Using netbeans 11.0 
JDK 12
```

I tried to see some available solutions on stackoverflow itself.

This is my Pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>Calculator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Calculator</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>gproject.calculator.MainApp</mainClass>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>12.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>12.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <
build>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>gproject.calculator.MainApp</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

<
/build>

<
/project>
```

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD FAILURE
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 4.614 s Finished at: 2019-05-27T00:49:24+05:30 Final
>   Memory: 14M/40M
>
> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java
>   (default-cli) on project Calculator: The parameters 'mainClass' for
>   goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or
>   invalid -> [Help 1]
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException**

Comment: It seems like maven cannot find your main class from your package.Can you please provide your directory structure .And cross verify if your class name and package is correct in pom.

Comment: Hello Mr Ananthapadmanabhan. Thanks for answering. As the issue is resolved now. Some code was missing in pom.xml and my friend helped me to resolve it.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your answer here ,so that it might be of help to someone else in future.

Comment: Sure i will now in a minute

Answer (score 0):

I added some line of code under tag **Plugins** in **my pom.xml file.**
Also, I referred to a **youtube video**.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCdBmPfzeyM
Make sure to watch the full video.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>  

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>

        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>gproject.calculator.MainApp</mainClass>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```